# What affects the Psychiatric Report

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

At the conclusion of the final mission, once the credits have rolled, you are treated to a *Psychiatric Report*.

What in-game actions effect the contents of this?

What possible results are there?

Comment: From researching this, it looks to be a very big answer.

Comment: @zerostack, from what I've seen each line of the report seems to be controlled by one or two statistics. With 15 lines, it would be a large answer, but not prohibitively so.

Comment: And also does that Psychiatric report pertain to Michael alone or all the characters?

Comment: @Dredd, I think it is a general assessment since the user name appears on the report (not any of the character's names).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Regardless of the path chosen, GTA 5 ends with a custom psychological profile molded by a player’s in-game actions. These profiles are tailored to each player's
>   style and decision-making process.

[Here is an example report posted on IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/GTA_5_Ending):

[image]

From what I noticed and what ChargingPun mentioned, there are 15 lines in the report that coorelate to a specific statistic.

## 1.)

- Dull but at least they have insurance.
- An intriguing case.
- Remarkable - a true sociopath.
- Hmmmm... words fail me.
- I sincerely hope someone arrests this maniac very soon.
- Deranged. Seriously deranged.
- Bit of a confusing case - not really sure where to begin.
- Not sure what to make of this one - interesting, up to a point, but also very, very boring.

## 2.)

- Classic fence sitter!
- Cannot make up mind - seemingly about anything.
- Tries to do the right thing - poor judgement as to what that is.
- Occasionally makes complex choices.
- Definitely incapable of making a real decision.
- Good at compromise.  Not so good at willpower

## 3.)

- Scared of ageing. Which is a worry.
- Doesn't hate self as much as any sane person would.
- Classic case of father issues
- Very large ego.
- Self justifying fool.
- in love with finding a reason as to why awful decisions are correct
- In thrall to own baser desires.

## 4.) Amount spent on buying useless stuff

- Mean. Very mean.
- Throws money around very freely - suggest sexual inadequacies - must investigate further.
- Too easy with money
- Pointlessly mean with money.
- Irresponsible with money and with rest of life.
- Reckless financially.

## 5.)

- At times, can be oddly morally superior, which is incredible.
- Superior - despite many obvious inadequacies.
- Loves to act like a big shot
- Prone to being judgmental about some weaknesses but not own.
- Likes to buy attention.

## 6.) Dependant on getting private lap dances or taking the strippers back to your safe house for a night of "fun".

- Sexually repressed, which is a good thing.
- Has some moral boundaries, it seems - just nowhere near enough.
- Likes to use people
- Seeks out love… in wrong places.
- Repressed, in some ways - mostly sexual. Definitely a confusing area - must investigate further.
- Possibly homosexual. Not sure they even know - imagine we will chat for many, many years, then they'll run off with a trucker.
- Sexually judgmental about some things.
- Treats women respectfully - when not killing them or their husbands
- Definite whore / Madonna complex. More on the whore side of things.

## 7.)Dependant on Ignoring or accepting the calls that initiates Michael's Family Side Missions.

- Loves family - having met them, not sure quite why.
- Family minded for some reason.
- Ignores family life
- Will probably get left by family.
- Loyal to crazy family, which I suppose is a start.
- Family minded.
- Ignores people closest to him

## 8.)Dependant on dollar amount invested in the Stock Market and results (making a profit or not).

- Keen to be part of American dream, which is odd.
- Scared of adult world.
- Thinks they are a wise type who sees the bigger picture.
- Falls for get rich quick schemes and other easy way outs.
- Likes white collar crime almost as much as the blue collar variety.
- Wisely invests money - in insane speculations
- Investor type - which is odd given risk taking as unlikely to make old bones.

## 9.)

- I wish I knew what meds to offer them - arsenic?
- Terrifyingly insular.
- Prone to random and futile outbursts of violence
- Psychopath or sociopath? Both.
- Vindictive in the extreme.
- Frighteningly myopic about suffering (of others)
- Vindictive bully.

## 10.)Dependant on amount of Robbing Stores, Stealing Cars

- At least keeps the car stealing to minimum.
- Respects some property rights - not others, of course.
- Serial thief
- Thieving kept to something of a minimum.
- Seems to prefer well considered crimes - in some instances.
- Tends to not steal too much more than situation requires - is that a good thing? I have no idea anymore
- Kleptomaniac
- Frighteningly cold hearted about other people when it comes to property, etc.

## 11.) Related to total time spent doing yoga:

- Well, the yoga was not popular. Unlike the murder.
- Tried yoga - stuck to mayhem. Great.
- Now they are interested in yoga?
- Yoga? No. not so much. Happier with lunacy.
- Tried yoga but preferred murder?
- Wonder if devotion to yoga will influence murderous rages?
- Attempts at spirituality not successful.  Unlike crime career.
- I thought yoga was meant to calm the mind?

## 12.) Related to total time spent playing sports:

- Over exercise not a vice! At least there's one...
- Physically unambitious.
- At least they don't over exercise
- A freak of many things, but not of physical fitness.
- At least they don't over exercise.
- Psychotic about most things, but not exercise.
- Lazy, lazy, lazy

## 13.) Amount of "Strangers and Freaks" Side mission initiated

- Seems to like strange people.
- Friendly, but terrifying.
- Easily distracted and eager to try new things, meet new people, cause new trouble!
- Like strangers.
- Seems to prefer a predictable life to the chaos of real life - unless they are one causing chaos.
- Crazy but outgoing.
- Avoids new people

## 14.)

- A.D.D. ?
- Possible A.D.D.?
- Distracted
- Not able to really finish things they start.
- Easily distracted
- Lazy in some ways.

## 15.)

- Will make me retire... and emigrate.
- Bizarre case study in excess.
- Don't know exactly what to make of this one.
- Needs a lot of help - as do I!
- Hmm - probably one to write about in next book.
- Help!
- In my professional opinion, this one is a fucking nut job.

Sources: [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/GTA_5_Ending), [Neoseaker](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/55711/t1904766-your-psyciatric-report-very-minor-endgame-spoiler/), [IGN Thread](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/for-those-who-finished-gta-v-what-was-your-psychiatric-report.453382183/),

Comment: I will continue to add to this.

Comment: Here is a good research: https://youtu.be/651YIFFJKKc